# Device based redirection on CloudFront serving from S3 origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a way to redirect the user to the mobile version of a web app say `m.foobar.com` based on the `User Agent` header using CloudFront?

I did read up on header caching using the user's device type using `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` header. But, I can only whitelist it if I'm using a custom origin to serve my assets (ELB or an EC2 instance). In such a scenario, I could edit my server configuration to handle the redirection.

However, I'm using S3 to serve my application now and would prefer a solution within the CloudFront/S3 ecosystem.

*Edit:*
For S3 distributions, I DONOT have access to the `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` and other CF headers.
[image: This is all that's available]

Any help, pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Background Material: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve it.

**Lambda@Edge Function**

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /*
     * If mobile, redirect to mobile domain
    */
    const isMobileHeader = 'CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer'

    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const headers = request.headers;

    let response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    if (headers[isMobileHeader.toLowerCase()] && headers[isMobileHeader.toLowerCase()] == "true") {
        response = {
        status: '302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: 'http://m.foobar.com',
            }],
        },
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

**CloudFront Distribution**

```
Behaviours:
  Default:
    Cache Based on Selected Request Headers: Whitelist
    Whitelist Headers:
      - CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer
    Lambda Function Associations:
      Event Type: Viewer Response
      Lambda Function ARN:  [ARN of function from Lambda@Edge Function]
```

**Further Reading**

- [Lambda@Edge](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html)
- [Lambda@Edge Example functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html)

**Edit 1**

Turns out S3 Origins, as Sanjay pointed out are [limited to a select set of headers for caching](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/header-caching.html#header-caching-web-selecting).

My suggestion for this would be to change from an S3 Origin, to a Custom Origin, using [S3 Static Website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html), which we can then target as a Custom Origin.

**S3 Bucket Configuration**

```
S3 Bucket:
  Properties:
    Static Website Hosting: Use this bucket to host a website
```

Note the Endpoint name that you are given on this page, you will need it for the next step.

**CloudFront Updates**

```
Origins:
  Create Origin:
    Origin Domain Name: [Endpoint from above]
    Origin ID: Custom-S3StaticHosting
Behaviours:
  Default:
    Origin: Custom-S3StaticHosting
```

Comment: The solution is a perfect fit if I'm to use an ELB origin to forward my content. But seemingly, the Whitelist headers `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` is not applicable for S3 distribution. 
For S3 distributions, only 3 headers are 'whitelistable': `Access-Control-Request-Method`, `Access-Control-Request-Headers` and `Origin`.

Comment: What if you use the static website endpoint like `[bucket].s3-website-[region].amazonaws.com`. this value can also be found on the **Static Website Hosting** settings page of your s3 bucket.

Comment: My origin is the fully qualified domain name of the S3 bucket whose format is kinda like this `xxxx.s3.amazonaws.com`. 
All of the website redirection docs on the AWS docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html) addresses static redirection based on keys, errors etc.; but none based on dynamic properties like user location/device.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for this by changing from an **S3 origin** to a **Custom origin**

Comment: I saw ```headers['cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer']
               && headers['cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer'][0].value === 'true'``` from aws docs(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-redirecting-examples). Maybe aws updated their headers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve it.

You don't need to perform a redirect for mobile apps. (Avoid redirect when possible) You can use the same url to serve desktop or mobile contents.

In your cloudfront whitelist, just whitelist `CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer` header. That will cache the contents based on your device.

Implement Viewer Request Lambda Edge and add it to CloudFront.
Lambda Edge is to program pop or CloudFront before the request gets to server.

In the LambdaEdge, verify the User-Agent header and classify whether you want to serve mobile or desktop contents. If mobile, then you can change the origin url to serve from mobile contents, else you can change it to desktop contents or default content.

You get your http headers in the User Request LambdaEdge.

**Lambda Edge Documentation:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html

Sample node implementation is available on the reference page.

If you really want to perform a redirect, you can do that with viewer response and make decision-based on the device header received.

A sample implementation of **viewer response** is covered in this blog,

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/lambdaedge-intelligent-processing-of-http-requests-at-the-edge/

The above implementation just spits back all the headers that it received, instead of sending 200 OK, the code need to be modified for 3xx status with the redirect location.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently at **viewer response** we don't have access to CloudFront-Is-X-Viewer headers even after setting them as whitelisted and moreover **status** header is read-only. I've solved it by triggering at **origin request**:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const name = 'cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer';
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
const headers = request.headers;

if (headers[name] && headers[name][0].value == "true") {
    callback(null, {
        status:'302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
            location: [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: `http://m.example.com${request.uri}`,
            }]
        }
    })
}

callback(null, request);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

How to add decoder with this code for nodejs, i use this code but its give me a string of character(How to decode it URi string)
**Sorry for i add it to answer because i have low reputation**

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const name = 'cloudfront-is-mobile-viewer';
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
const headers = request.headers;

if (headers[name] && headers[name][0].value == "true") {
     callback(null, {
        status:'302',
        statusDescription: 'Found',
           headers: {
        location: [{
            key: 'Location',
            value: `http://m.example.com${request.uri}`,
        }]
    }
})
```

}

callback(null, request);
};